# Nextjs: removing element on unmount of a component

Tags: next.js

Any idea how does one remove an element from the dom in nextjs on componentwillunmount?
I'm using the Head component to load a JS script that generates an element on a page.
When I navigate to another page, that element still stays so I need to remove it.
I thought of using componentwillunmount and document.getelementbyclassname, but it doesn't work in nextjs for some reason.

Any thoughts on how to solve it?

This doesn't do anything, even though the button is being picked up:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    oldButton2 = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (oldButton2.parentNode) {
      oldButton2.parentNode.removeChild(oldButton2);
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is an api for the lib that gets loaded? if so use it to remove the button.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible. Need a way to remove it based on the page. Does NextJs miss that functionality?

Comment: It is not related to Next, it manages things that went through it, but it can't know about side effect of some loaded scripts.

Comment: You can register to an event of route change, and there do your thing.